# Make a legend to divide information from data into two

Tags: r, legend

The data y and x is divided into females and males.I want to show with a legend 'red' for females and 'blue' for males in my graph. I have tried with the following code, but I dont know whether the blue or red is for males=1 or females=0?

```
 x          y        Gender       
32840   0,55516685     0
23640   0,58716721     0
30984   0,56230706     1
22960   0,59569562     1
27808   0,61195034     1
39104   0,57468795     1
20920   0,61508139     0
30496   0,58029317     0



mod1 = lm(y~x, data=data)
modsum = summary(mod1)

plot(data$x, data$y, col =c("red", "blue"), pch = 19, type = 'p', las =1, 
     xlab = expression(paste('RD')),
     ylab = 'FA') 
abline(mod1)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please add a minimal section of your data using dput(). Also, why are you plotting data$y vs data$y?

Comment: Did you really mean `plot(data$y, data$y,  ...`  or did you want `plot(data$x, data$y, ...`

Comment: Sorry, I of course meant y vs. x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data$col <- ifelse(data$Gender == 0 , "red", "blue") 
plot(data$x, data$y, col = data$col, pch = 19, type = 'p', las =1, 
     xlab = expression(paste('RD')),
     ylab = 'FA')
legend("topright", legend=c("male", "female"),col=c("blue", "red"), pch = c(19,19))
abline(mod1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect, there is no variable to designate male or female in the plot, by assigning `col=c("red, "blue")` you are simply alternating colors with no assignation to gender.

Comment: Good, that is correct. To Zahra, see the output of `x=1:10`, `y=1:10`, `plot(x, y, col=c("red", "blue"))`.  Therefore @ed_sans correction `data$col <- ifelse(data$Gender == 0 , "red", "blue") ` is necessary to provide a correct vector of colors to the plot that match the gender assignment.

Comment: @Zahra, please, also look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)